# MATLAB - Generate a random matrix taking different strings from other ararys

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 3 different arrays of strings in Matlab, these contain different departure times.

One array is for departures at '07:00', '07:10'.....
The next arrays is for departures at '08:00','08:10'...
And the third is for departures at '09:00','09:10'..

Now I want to create a new matrix/array take take random values from these 3 arrays and puts it into a new matrix with 1000 inputs, how can i do this?

code:

```
SevenOclock = ["07:00","07:05","07:10","07:15","07:20","07:25","07:30","07:35","07:40","07:45","07:50","07:55"]'
EightOclock = ["08:00","08:05","08:10","08:15","08:20","08:25","08:30","08:35","08:40","08:45","08:50","08:55"]'
NineOclock  = ["09:00","09:05","09:10","09:15","09:20","09:25","09:30","09:35","09:40","09:45","09:50","09:55"]'

randomDeparture = rand(SevenOclock; EightOclock; NineOclock) %NOT WORKING!! HELP
```

Could someone plz help me?

Comment: While `rand` is not the function you need, you are not even using MATLAB syntax, as `rand[]` is a syntax error!

Comment: https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html

Comment: Sorry dude, I am new to Matlab :P

Comment: @Giroud2 that is not an acceptable excuse. You should be able to write functional code. If you ask for help, it is expected from you to make the minimal effort on solving it yourself, and this definitely implies not writing invalid code with syntax not from MATLAB. No ofense please, come aroudn here anytime! but make an effort to solve it yourself first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `randsample`, to sample randomly. The code, tidied up, would look like this:

```
minutes = ["00";"05";"10";"15";"20";"25";"30";"35";"40";"45";"50";"55"];

SevenOclock  = "07:" + minutes;
EightOclock  = "08:" + minutes;
NineOclock   = "09:" + minutes;

allDepartures=[SevenOclock;EightOclock;NineOclock];

randomDeparture = randsample(allDepartures,1000,true);
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Error using randsample (line 131)
K must be less than or equal 36 for sampling without replacement

I think this error occurs because the arrays "allDepartures" has 36 rows

Comment: @Giroud2 sorry my answer was edited and I missed that. Check the last edit, now it should work. Basically now we allow the samples to be repeated (else we can only pick 36!)

Comment: Ye that`s what I thought! Thanks so much dude!!! I love this forum so much :D How can I give you positive feedback here?

Comment: @Giroud2 thanks! Up-voting and accepting my answer is the way of giving positive feedback! Please do upvote other people too when you find their work useful! If you still can not, worry not, you go earning points as you go participating here.